# Сравнение на лету двух числовых значений в inputах

Tags: javascript, input

Есть инпуты

```
<input type="number" name="minim" value="" />
<input type="number" name="maxim" value="" />
```

Как бы это их сравнивать на лету, чтобы юзер не мог ввести в `minim` значение больше, чем на данный момент введено в `maxim`, и наоборот, не мог ввести в `maxim` цифру меньше, чем на данный момент введена в `minim`?

То есть, вот он ввел в `maxim` число 5000, значит в `minim` он может ввести не больше, чем 4999.

Спасибо!

Comment: чистый js&html?

Comment: @bonusrk да, ну или jquery

Comment: самый "прямой" вариант добавить им атрибуты `min` & `max` и повесить на оба листенеры, чтобы обоюдно менять эти атрибуты по изменениям в инпутах.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var min = document.querySelector('[name="minim"]')
var max = document.querySelector('[name="maxim"]')

min.addEventListener('input', ()=> max.min = min.valueAsNumber+1)
max.addEventListener('input', ()=> min.max = max.valueAsNumber-1)

min.addEventListener('blur',
()=> max.valueAsNumber < min.valueAsNumber && (min.value = max.valueAsNumber-1))
max.addEventListener('blur',
()=> min.valueAsNumber > max.valueAsNumber && (max.value = min.valueAsNumber+1))
```

```html
<input type="number" name="minim" value="" />
<input type="number" name="maxim" value="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
const el_min = document.querySelector('input[name=minim]')
const el_max = document.querySelector('input[name=maxim]')

el_min.addEventListener('input', xxx)
el_max.addEventListener('input', xxx)

function xxx(e) {
  if (e.target.name == 'minim' && +e.target.value > +el_max.value && el_max.value)
    el_min.value = el_max.value - 1

  if (e.target.name == 'maxim' && +e.target.value < +el_min.value && el_min.value)
    el_max.value = +el_min.value + 1
}
```

```html
<input type="number" name="minim" value="" />
<input type="number" name="maxim" value="" />
```

Comment: Попробуйте набрать в мин "5", а после в макс "25"

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
 <div id="form">
  MIN<input id="inp_min" type="number" name="minim" value="" />
  MAX<input id="inp_max" type="number" name="maxim" value="" />
 </div>

 <script type="text/javascript">
  "use strict";

  let inp_min = document.getElementById("inp_min");
  let inp_max = document.getElementById("inp_max");

  inp_min.addEventListener("blur", dec);
  inp_max.addEventListener("blur", dec);


  function dec(e) {
   if (e.target.id === "inp_min" && inp_max.value && +e.target.value >= +inp_max.value) {
    e.target.value = (+inp_max.value-1);
   } else if (e.target.id === "inp_max" && inp_min.value && +e.target.value <= +inp_min.value) {
    e.target.value = (+inp_min.value+1);
   }
  }
  
 </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Почитайте коммент под ответом @hu-fo-of-ex